# Why can't I move the control points in all 3 dimentions?

Tags: bezier-curves

The movement of the control points on my bezier curve is restricted to X and Z, while I want them to move in the Y-axis too. Why is this so? Thank you.

P.S. This was never an issue with other bezier curves I have worked on.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you accidentally chose "2D" instead of "3D" ? (in the Shape tab of the curve)

Comment: Thank you! yes, silly of me :)  @thibsert